# Canvas in Wrappanel

Tags: c#, windows, canvas, windows-phone-8

I´m facing a Problem, can someone tell me whats wrong with this code:

First I create 2 Canvas:

```
private void AddItem()
    {
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
        Canvas myCanvas2 = new Canvas();
        myCanvas2.Height = 128;
        myCanvas2.Width = 104;
        myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        myCanvas.Height = 200;
        myCanvas.Width = 350;
        myCanvas2.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5,10,0,0);
        myCanvas.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(66, 10, 0, 0);
```

Then I create three Textblocks:

First: Add a TextBlock to first Canvas:

```
TextBlock TextBlock1= new TextBlock();
    TextBlock1.FontSize = 48;
    TextBlock1.Text = Fach.Text;
    Canvas.SetTop(TextBlock1, 10);
    Canvas.SetLeft(TextBlock1, 29);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(TextBlock1);
```

Second: Add a second TextBlock to first Canvas:

```
TextBlock TextBlock2= new TextBlock();
    TextBlock2.FontSize = 24;
    TextBlock2.Text = Raum.Text;
    Canvas.SetTop(TextBlock2, 79);
    Canvas.SetLeft(TextBlock2, 31);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(TextBlock2);
```

Third: Add a second TextBlock to second Canvas:

```
TextBlock TextBlock3 = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock3.FontSize = 20;
    TextBlock3.Text = Zeit;
    Canvas.SetTop(TextBlock3, 36);
    Canvas.SetLeft(TextBlock3, 10);
    myCanvas2.Children.Add(TextBlock3);
```

Add myCanvas and myCanvas2 to wrappanel:

```
wrapPanel.Children.Add(myCanvas);
    wrapPanel.Children.Add(myCanvas2);
    }
    };
```

The first Canvas(myCanvas) is showing up(The box) but the second Canvas(myCanvas2) should be showing up in front of myCanvas. Somone know why? Because of the wappanel? How can I change this?

Edit: Xaml

```
  <phone:PivotItem x:Name="Montag" Header="Montag" Margin="24,27,0,1">



                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >


                        <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical"/>


                </ScrollViewer>  

</phone:PivotItem>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it works fine, I can see all Canvas and TextBoxes.

Comment: Oh just a typo in my code! But I want the second Canvas to be on the left/ in front of the first Canvas do you know how to do this

Comment: First problem... you're coding xaml using C#.  Second, you are completely missing out on the benefits of binding against data.

Comment: Oh..ok this is my first Windows Phone application, so im not really into all the things I can do! I´m using c# because I want to create these Canvas on runtime dynamically. And can´t figure out how to do this with xaml

Comment: Also, the second canvas has to be added after the first.  XAML is designed to be order-specific.

Comment: @user2127925 normally you would have an ItemsControl of some sort that binds to an observable collection of some type, then use DataTemplates to display data for a particular type.  I would strongly suggest you investigate MVVM and create some prototypes to learn the true power behind WPF/Silverlight/WP UI development.

Comment: Ok Thank you im going to look at it. But do you have an quick fix for my Problem above? Is this even possible? Just to know how to do it in c#

Answer (score 1):

please double check your code. i guess that this line is incorrect:

```
TextBlock3.Text = Zeit;
```

i think you should add ".Text" to Zeit => "Zeit.Text";

other lines seems correct.

Hope Helps You.